# Check if two regular expressions are equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-expressions

I thought I proved that those two regular expressions are and identity using induction. But my friend told me that there was a counterexample. I am not sure anymore.

$$(1(1 + 0)^*)^* = (10^*)^*$$

Comment: What is $10^*$ for example? Can you please explain your expressions more?

Comment: @AgentS I think 110 is in both languages

Comment: For a formal proof, see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445649/proving-the-regular-expression-identity-aa-b-ab).

Answer (score 3):

$1(1 + 0)^*$ is the language of all words over alphabet $\{0,1\}$ which start with $1$. If we split them before the $1$s, we see that $1(1+0)^* = (10^*)^+$. But in general $$(L^+)^* = L^*$$ so you are correct.

Comment: Thanks, that's reassuring.