# Proving the regular expression identity $(a(a + b)^*)^* = (ab^*)^*$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, regular-expressions

I'm struggling to prove the regular expression identity
$$(a(a+b)^*)^* = (ab^*)^*$$

The recommendation is to use induction on the star operator. My strategy was to first prove that $$(a(a+b)^*)^* \subseteq (ab^*)^*$$ and then prove $$(ab^*)^* \subseteq (a(a+b)^*)^*$$

I started with the first one, using induction on the inner start of the left side. So the base case is:
$$(a\epsilon)^* \subseteq (ab^*)^*$$
Which holds. Then For the inductive hypothesis I assume:
$$(aX)^*\subseteq(a)$$
And then set out to prove
$$(aX(a+b)^*)^* \subseteq (ab^*)^*$$
Now I know there is a set identity that would make it sufficient to prove:
$$(aX(a+b)^*) \subseteq (ab^*)$$
Then by the I.H:
$$(a(ab^*)^*(a+b)^*) \subseteq (ab^*)$$
And this is as far as I've been able to get! I don't know how to manipulate what I have here to reach the goal. Am I on the right track? Any hints, identities that could be useful to help me finish this proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a(a + b)^*$ is a followed by any number of a's and b's.
$((a(a + b)^*)^*$ is the same with the addition of the empty string.

$(ab^*)^*$ includes the empty string and any string of a's and b's begining with a.

So the regular expressions are equivalent.
The advise of induction with * is confusing.
Do they mean double induction for the iterated use of *?

This Mathjax thing can be obnoxious when the preview is different than how the answer appeares, thus requiring additional, unexpected editing.

Answer (score 0):

Let me follow your strategy. The inclusion $(ab^*)^* \subseteq (a(a+b)^*)^*$ is easy to prove as follows 
$$
b \subseteq a+b \implies b^* \subseteq (a+b)^* \implies ab^* \subseteq a(a+b)^* \implies (ab^*)^* \subseteq (a(a+b)^*)^*
$$
For the opposite inclusion, I interpret the recommendation as follows: 
prove by induction on $n$ that, for all $n$, 
$$
(1) \quad a(a+b)^n \subseteq (ab^*)^*.
$$
For $n = 0$, the result is trivial. Suppose that the formula holds for $n$. Then 
$$
a(a+b)^{n+1} = a(a+b)^n(a+b) \subseteq (ab^*)^*(a+b) = (ab^*)^*a +(ab^*)^*b
$$
It suffices now to observe that $(ab^*)^*a \subseteq (ab^*)^*ab^*  \subseteq (ab^*)^*$ and $(ab^*)^*b  \subseteq (ab^*)^*$ to prove (1).

Of course, (1) implies $a(a+b)^* \subseteq (ab^*)^*$, whence $(a(a+b)^*)^* \subseteq (ab^*)^*$.

N.B. For a purely formal proof, you could try to use the axioms of a [Kleene algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra), but it is probably not in the spirit of what you were asked for.